# Condensing multiple echo statements into one in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am relatively new to PHP and want to know a more efficient way of echo'ing the following in less steps or even just one statement.

```
echo '<div class="title-area"><a href="';
echo site_url();
echo '">';
echo get_bloginfo( 'name' );
echo '</a></div>';
```

Currently this outputs a div containing a link of the blog title and a href of the site.

Comment: various ways you can write strings are concatenation (see Sulthan below), multiple echos, multiple echoes into an output buffer (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php), HERE/NOW doc notation (see https://php.net/language.types.string) or ending PHP mode with ``?>`` and outputting raw HTML (you can punctuate it with individual ``<?= $var ?>`` statements to concatenate processed PHP values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this

```
echo '<div class="title-area"><a href="'.site_url().'">'.get_bloginfo( 'name' ).'</a></div>';
```

You just need to use [concatinate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) instead of `echo` it multiple times

Comment: perfect. I was missing the initial and trailing period on site_url() and get_bloginfo( 'name' ). (When I tried to concatenate this before) Thanks!